# Wildlfy deployment failed

Tags: java, wildfly

I've tried to deploy my application using Wildfly Management Console (wildfly 10.1.0.Final) but unfortunately failed due to the following reason / error :

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"MyApplication.war\" Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication.war\".POST_MODULE"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

I used **Replace Deployment** function provided on the console. I've used the same function to upload my **.war** application before this and successfully deployed.

I've tested my application locally and it can be deployed and executed without any errors.

Comment: I've been seeing this outOfMemory error for long time in my wildfly server while replacing the deployment. Everytime this error occurs, I simply restart the wildfly server and everything works again. So I didn't even care to research on this matter as restarting always worked for me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the standalone.conf (or standalone.conf.bat if using windows) in a text editor. The file is located in the bin folder of your Wildfly server.

Search for the text -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize.
It may have the value `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m

Increase 256m to 512m. And restart JBoss server. Try to deploy again.

If you are still getting this error, you can increase 512m to 1g but that might be a overkill. `

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the content of your standalone.xml or conf file. What is your JAVA_OPTS settings?

From the error log you have given, it looks like Wildfly is throwing OOM exception for the metadata space. Increase the value of the parameter `XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`.